# not erroring but not creating anything

Tags: python

Any idea why my code isn't creating the files in the created location?  It ran once but now it creates nothing.

```
from sys import argv
from fpdf import FPDF
import json
import csv


def write_cover_letter(cover_letter, skills):

    # open csv file and read input
    with open(skills) as skills_csv:

        reader = csv.reader(skills_csv)
        rownum = 0

        for row in reader:

            pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4')  # portrait mode, mm , A4 size paper
            pdf.add_page()  # new blank page
            pdf.set_font('Arial', '', 12)  # font, Style (B,U,I) , fontsize in pt.

            #ignore the header row
            if rownum == 0:
                pass

            else:
                model_cover_letter = open(cover_letter, 'r')

                for line in model_cover_letter:

                    line = line.replace('#website', row[0])
                    line = line.replace('#inserttools', ','.join(row[1].split('#')))  # skills are seperated by '#' split and join them
                    line = line.replace('#toolproficient', row[2])
                    line = line.replace('#toolyr', row[3])
                    line = line.replace('#company', row[4])

                    pdf.write(6, line)

                pdf.output('cover_letters/Cover Letter - ' + row[4] + '.pdf', 'F')
                pdf.close()

            rownum = rownum + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    coverletter = argv[1]
    skillset = argv[2]

    # just use the right file names or modify the ones provided
    write_cover_letter(coverletter, skillset)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: is it a typo, or did you actually write`if name=="main"` instead of `if name=="__main__"`?

Comment: I wrote "__ name  (two more underscores here)__" == "__ main __ " 
Stackoverflow doesn't like the 2 underscores I guess.

Comment: @bsayles15 If you don't type `__` inside a code block, it translates to bold: i.e. `__hello__` becomes __hello__ :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I see 2 main issues here.
The first one is that you open the file purely in read mode, so there's no way for you to edit it anyway.

```
model_cover_letter = open(cover_letter, 'r') #will allow to only read
model_cover_letter=open(cover_letter,'r+') # open for both reading and writing
model_cover_letter=open(cover_letter,'w') # open for only writing(truncating)
```

Secondly, `for` loop makes a copy of the variable, so you are basically just changing the local copy of the variable there.

I would do it this way: open the file in read mode, copy the content, edit it. Then, open the file in write mode and write the edited info there.

```
model_cover_letter = open(cover_letter, 'r')
file_content=model_cover_letter.read() # store the content
model_cover_letter.close()
model_cover_letter = open(cover_letter, 'w')
file_content=file_content.split('\n') # split the content by lines

# using index we can change the data
for index in len(file_content):
          file_content[i]=file_content[i].replace('#website', row[0])
          file_content[i]=file_content[i].replace('#inserttools', ','.join(row[1].split('#'))) 
          file_content[i]=file_content[i].replace('#toolproficient', row[2])
          file_content[i]=file_content[i].replace('#toolyr', row[3])
          file_content[i]=file_content[i].replace('#company', row[4])
#write each line to the file
for line in file_content:
          model_cover_letter.write(line)
model_cover_letter.close()
```

Also, pay attention to the last symbol in your file. If it is `\n` , use `len(file_content)-1` because your last element will be `''`(and there will be an issue with replacing). Otherwise, this loop should work fine

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I changed it but it's still not creating the folder and putting the new files in that folder.  The key line I want it to execute is pdf.output('cover_letters/Cover Letter - ' + row[4] + '.pdf', 'F').  I read that fpdf only works in Python 2 and is experimental in Python 3.  It doesn't work in Python 2.7.  Could it be something else?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't directly worked with fpdf, so I can't tell that for sure. I took a look at the website and it seems like all major functions should be supported in Python 3.4+. Still, where exactly are you creating a folder in your code?